# Flask Nginx Guincorn/uwsgi docker configuration

Tags: python, nginx, docker, flask, digital-ocean

I want to setup a Flask webiste on digitalocean with some links that launch some games either backed by tornando/twisted or to other Flask websites. The architecture for the website can be shown in the following diagram:

[image: Arch]

Most of the tutorials I have seen [Example 1](https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/deploy-flask-docker-nginx/), [Example 2](http://feisky.xyz/2015/02/11/how-to-use-docker-compose-to-deploy-a-flask-app/) , [Example 3](http://vladikk.com/2013/09/12/serving-flask-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/) and some stackoverflow answers deal with this in one fashion or another. My issues with them is:

(a) Example 1 while being ridiculously easy, is opaque. It does not help me to understand ngnix, gunicorn properly to enable me to set up my application as shown in the figure above.

(b) Example 2, is what I am trying to use but when I go to my site url, it defaults to the nginx web page. <s>I would post the link to the full problem.</s> [The link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44731773/nginx-not-serving-my-flask-website)

(c) Example 3, does not use Docker.

My questions is this:

(a) Is my proposed architecture even feasible with the combination of Docker, Flask, Nginx and uwsgi/gunicorn? Is there a better way?

(b) Should I even use Docker? I wanted to use Docker to learn how to use docker-compose and eventually Docker Swarm, but if it is too much of hassle, I am willing to drop the idea entirely.

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: @Damian Lattenero I wanted to know what architecture I could use. Should I split the question into architecture and specific problem, post the architecture question on softwareengineering.stackenchange.com?

Comment: @Foon The question I wanted to specifically solve is https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147500/discussion-between-corax-and-cricket-007. Could I delete the on-hold question? But I feel that this question in the link above, without the context of the above on-hold question might not be solved correctly. Oh well, thanks for your correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **nginx** is your reverse proxy: it directs calls from a url to the proper server. You need nginx to be able to receive requests from multiple URL / domain names on to the same IP address: for example if site1.example.com, site2.example.com and site3.example.com all have a DNS record pointing to IP 111.222.333.444, nginx can understand that site1.example.com is your server1, site2 is server2 etc... (even if all these 'servers' are hosted on the same VM.
- **uwsgi/gunicorn** is the server engine that Flask runs on.
- **Flask** is the framework that helps you build the site, and runs on uwsgi/gunicorn.
- **Docker** helps you containerize the apps (i.e. make them easy to deploy, reproducible no matter where you deploy)

So, in your case, you should use a Docker container per app, they can all run uwsgi/gunicorn on port 8000 for example, and serve your apps.
With docker, on deploy, you can expose these containers with different ports (like app1->8000, app2->8001, app3->8002)

Then nginx should be exposed to the outside (i.e. port 443 for HTTPS/SSL, 80 for HTTP) and redirect requests per domain/url to the proper server port.

look for nginx multiple domains to find example config file for this purpose (like https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: Thanks. That helped to clarify things.

Comment: note: the app servers should be exposed on localhost only (IP 127.0.0.1) while the nginx container is exposed to the outside. If you were to expose the apps on ports 8001-8003 to 0.0.0.0, they'd be reachable through these ports directly from outside, which you probably don't want, especially if you want to handle SSL connections (if you have any kind of authentication mechanism, you want SSL). With direct access, even if you reach the server with HTTPS, the connection would not be encrypted, because the app server doesn't handle the SSL part. This is what nginx does)

Comment: so what you are saying is that the Flask website/apps should only be reachable from the nginx container, right? Can I do that from the docker-compose file or when I am setting up my containers? Thanks again for your input.

Comment: yes. in the compose file you can define the port as 8000:127.0.0.1:8001 for example

Comment: actually, my bad, it's 127.0.0.1:8000:8001